# Autohotkey script suddenly stopped working

Tags: autohotkey

This script just works awhile ago, but now it doesn't.

What the script does is to disable both the mouse pad and usb mouse after I press the middle button of my usb mouse... but now it doesn't. Is there something wrong?

```
mbutton::                    ;win + m hotkey
if (x != 1)
{
    BlockInput, MouseMove
    x := 1
    Hotkey, LButton, DoNothing
    Hotkey, RButton, DoNothing
    Hotkey, XButton1, DoNothing
    Hotkey, XButton2, DoNothing
    return
}
if (x = 1)
    reload

DoNothing:
return

F2::
Suspend
return
```

No other AHK script running, just this.

Comment: At a guess, you've pressed `F2`, which will suspend the script. Press `F2` again.

Comment: @RJFalconer pressing F2 will suspend the script, pressing usb mouse middle button will disable the mouse movement but will not suspend the script.

Comment: Yes, I see that. There's no reason this should not work, so I assumed you were running it and hit F2. Have you tried restarting AHK?

Comment: done restarting, still the same..